# How i can call or echo a variable from inside a plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hi every body i have a problem with my wordpress web site, as you know in order to share and make videos load and play on facebook wall we have to add a meta property in `header.php` of the web site theme like this one:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?> ">
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo (get_the_excerpt($post->ID, $shortname.'_video_url')); ?>">
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'blog' ); ?>"> 
<meta property="og:video" content="http://tvrisata.com/wp-content/plugins/proplayer/players/player.swf?file=http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/proplayer/playlist-controller.php?pp_playlist_id=1984pp-single-4fd12daceb632&sid=1339108781">                                                         
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="490">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="350">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="web site name">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="facebook id">
```

and the problem is that when I share a video post on facebook wall, facebook loads the correct thumbnail and when I click on that thumbnail it always plays the same video with the id "**pp_playlist_id=1984pp-single-4fd12daceb632&sid=1339108781**" and not the correct video. So if i want to get facebook playing the right video i have to insert a meta such this one:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://tvrisata.com/wp-content/plugins/proplayer/players/player.swf?file=http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/proplayer/playlist-controller.php?pp_playlist_id=1984pp-single-4fd12daceb632&sid=1339108781">
```

with the correct id of the video after `?`. My question is, how I can generate or get the correct id automatically inserted after `?` for each video post? The id is generated by the plugins and inserted in an embed as variables, so I try to call this variable after `?` mark but it is not working or maybe I made a mistake or that the variable is inside a plugin and not in the theme. I hope some one can help me with that.

I have revised plugin files but I am a beginner and I do not understand this completly. This is the link to the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/proplayer/ . Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have each Video Post under the category "Video". You can set a custom meta field called "videoLink" with the URL pointing to the correct video for that given post.

If the post isn't a video post, you can have a default video. So something like this would be a start:

```
<?php
$default = 'http://tvrisata.com/wp-content/plugins/proplayer/players/player.swf?file=http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/proplayer/playlist-controller.php?pp_playlist_id=1984pp-single-4fd12daceb632&sid=1339108781';
$videoLink = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'videoLink', true);
$video = $videoLink && is_category('Video') ? $videoLink : $default;
?>
...
<meta property="og:video" content="<?php echo $video; ?>">
```

This is a very basic implementation, but you should be able to understand how this works. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply but this is not actually what i am looking for you can check my answer i have added some details ,thank you  very much